# Fix warning message from Generic type usage

Tags: java, generics

I am able to run this program successfully.

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<T> {
    final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private int capacity;

    public FixedBlockingQueueGenerics(int capacity){
        super();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(capacity);
        System.out.println("Capactiy:"+this.capacity);
    }
    public BlockingQueue<T> getQueue(){
        return queue;
    }
    public void addElement(T element){
        try{
            queue.put(element);
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void startThreads(){
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        for ( int i =0; i < 10; i++){
            es.submit(new MyProducer<T>(this));
        }
        //es.submit(new MyConsumer(queue));
        new Thread(new MyConsumer<T>(this)).start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        FixedBlockingQueueGenerics f = new FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<Integer>(1);
        f.startThreads();
    }
}

class MyProducer<T> implements Runnable{

    private FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<T> queue;
    public MyProducer(FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<T> queue){
        this.queue = queue;     
    }
    public void run(){
        for ( int i=1; i< 5; i++){
            queue.addElement((T)new Integer(i));
            System.out.println("adding:"+i);
        }
    }
}

class MyConsumer<T> implements Runnable{
    private BlockingQueue<T>  queue;
    Integer firstNumber = 0;
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public MyConsumer(FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<T> fQueue){
        this.queue = fQueue.getQueue();
    }
    /* TODO : Compare two consecutive integers in queue are same or not*/
    public void run(){  
        Integer secondNumber = 0;
        while ( true){
            try{
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println("queue size:"+queue.size());

                if ( queue.size() > 0) {
                    secondNumber = (Integer)queue.remove();
                    System.out.println("Removed:"+secondNumber);
                    System.out.println("Numbers:Num1:Num2:"+firstNumber+":"+secondNumber);
                    if ( firstNumber.intValue() ==  secondNumber.intValue()){
                        System.out.println("Numbers matched:"+firstNumber);
                    }
                    firstNumber = secondNumber;
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception err){
                err.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to fix the warnings reported by compile by using  `-Xlint:unchecked`

The warning reported by compiler is:

```
FixedBlockingQueueGenerics.java:51: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
                        queue.addElement((T)new Integer(i));
                                            ^
  required: T
  found:    Integer
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class MyProducer
1 warning
```

Since the program runs successfully, I am unable to figure out fix for this warning message.

Since

```
queue.addElement(new Integer(i));
```

did not work, I change the line to

```
queue.addElement((T)new Integer(i));
```

Above change fixed the compilation issue but warning remains as it is.

Only after removing generic template, I get rid of warnings.

Comment: Well, that is obviously not type safe: `T` could be `String`. `queue` needs to be of type `FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<? super Integer>` for that to be safe.

Comment: `MyProducer` is simply not generic. Remove the type variable, and change `queue` (and the parameter to be assigned to `queue`) to have type `FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<? super Integer>`.

Comment: I'd rather guess that `MyProducer` should **not** have a type parameter, and receive a `FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<Integer>` - because it **is** producing `Integer` objects. (Analogously, the consumer should have a `BlockingQueue<Integer>` and no type parameter)

Comment: If I have to make this program to accept generic types ( Integer, Long etc.)., what should I do?

Comment: You can't have it generic for as long as you are adding `Integer` instances to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is warning you that you are doing something that may not be type safe. It *could* be OK under certain circumstances - e.g. if `T` is `Object` or `Integer` - just not in general - e.g. `T` could be `String`, or any other class.

`MyProducer`, as written, has no need for the type variable. Remove the type variable, and change `queue` (and the parameter to be assigned to `queue`) to have type `FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<? super Integer>`.

```
class MyProducer implements Runnable{

    private FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<? super Integer> queue;
    public MyProducer(FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<? super Integer> queue){
        this.queue = queue;     
    }
    public void run(){
        for ( int i=1; i< 5; i++){
            queue.addElement(new Integer(i));
            System.out.println("adding:"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try and test in 2 minutes

Comment: Do I have to change FixedBlockingQueueGenerics too with same change? replace T with ? extends Integer?

Comment: Not unless you always want to store `Integer`s in your queue.

Comment: Now I got this error: required: FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<? super Integer>
found: FixedBlockingQueueGenerics<T> for this line ( Producer constuction) : es.submit(new MyProducer(this));

Comment: Right. Follow through with making the necessary changes to satisfy the type bounds.

Comment: So, in fact, you do need to remove the generics from `FixedBlockingQueueGenerics`.

Comment: T extends Integer is not accepted unlike T extends Object in FixedBlockingQueueGenerics